# Bundle executable files for i386 and arm6/7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to compile libFLAC executable to inherit in my project to convert wav files to flac, however at current I have been successful for either or OR. Not both. I am trying to find out if there is a way to bundle for both i386 and arm6/7 architecture.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *lipo* on the output executables to bundle them together:

```
lipo -create -output <output> <input0> <input1>
```

So in your case you might have:

```
lipo -create -output libflac_bundled.a libflac_i386.a libflac_arm.a
```

Which will produce **libflac_bundled.a** containing both libraries.

Comment: Thats pretty awesome just curious can I have multiple inputs to go with this? like <input0> <input1> <input2>

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure about that, sorry.

Comment: @kforkarim as far as I can tell, yes, this is possible.